# How to make the becomeFirstRespoonder executes only once when tab item is selected out of 3 tabs

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developing an app which Have three tab bar Items.

When i click the second tab bar item, then the search bar needs to be automatically enabled like(search bar `becomeFirstResponder`).

I have done this in `viewWillAppear` method. So every time it is automatically becoming first responder. But I want only when tab bar item is selected that search bar has to `becomeFirstresponder`.

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabBarController: didSelectViewController:` for identifying when specific tab is pressed. And from there you can call `becomeFirstResponder`.

Comment: Ya I have done like that.but In my specific second view controller view will appear method I wrote like"search bar becomeFirstresponder".

Comment: For example I have three view controllers 1 2 3. When i click the second tab 2 view controller will be loaded.And in 2 view controller view will appear method I wrote search bar "becomeFirstresponder".the 2 view controller have tableview.when i click the table view of 2 view controller have shown some presentmodalviewcontroller.when i closse the present modal view controller again view will appear method executes and search bar becoming firstResponder.I want only when 2 tab is selected then only search bar should become firstResonder...help me please

Comment: You can create a bool property of view controller 2, and set that to yes when tab bar item is clicked, and in viewDidAppear set that to false, now when you move forward and backward in that view contoller heirarchy it will always be no, and based upon this bool value enable search bar.